# Using Python (and DataNitro) to copy cells from a particular sheet in one Excel workbook, to a particular sheet in another Excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

I do a lot of data analysis in Excel and have been exploring Python and DataNitro to streamline my workflow.  I specifically am trying to copy certain cells from one sheet in one Excel workbook, and paste them into certain cells in a certain sheet in another Excel workbook.
I have been storing ("copying") using CellRange (DataNitro), but am not sure how to copy the stored contents into a particular sheet, in another Excel workbook.  Any clue how I may go about this?  Also, is it possible to make the range defined for a CellRange conditional on certain cell properties?

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you, all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of copying:

```
data = CellRange("A1:A10").value
active_wkbk("Book2.xlsx")
CellRange("A1:A10").value = data
```

You can make the range conditional using regular Python logic (`if` statements, etc.).